# Ionic Desktop Testing

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Is there any advantage in testing the ionic app on a web browser using the the `ionic serve` command **vs** just running a local apache server and browsing the www folder (e.g. `http://localhost/www/#/app/home`). I checked the `serve.js` file in the npm module and apparently all it does is listening for a tcp connection on a default port using nodejs modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few advantages, but you are certainly able to use a local apache server as well.

**`ionic serve` benefits**

- It runs with the ability to have live reload, meaning if you save a file in your editor the app will auto-refresh in your browser. You can disable by with the `-r` flag on the command.
- It can open a browser when you start up, which can be nice or annoying. You can disable with the `-b` flag on the command.
- It sets up a local server for you, regardless if your files are in the apache www directory. It lets you store the files anywhere in your system.

**Apache benefits**

- You can setup .htaccess rules to rewrite urls to properly support html5mode in Angular. I don't do this on mobile apps since the urls are not available in apps.
- Runs on port 80. You don't have to worry about ports or remembering what port to use.

Its up to you really, but I use `ionic serve`. You can also use `cordova serve` which does the same as `ionic serve` without live reload and browser open, and runs on `localhost:8000`.

Comment: I'd add that ionic server will also auto run the ionicplatform.ready method - essentially "faking" a proper Cordova device.ready.